# Energy of a black hole : a quizz question

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

Consider a standard eternal Schwarzschild black hole of mass $M$. One wants to speak about the energy $E$ of a black hole, so let 's present this as a quizz.

1) This is a non-sense to speak about extended conserved quantities in General Relativity, including total energy.

2) $E=0$

3) $E=M$

4) Other results $(E = \frac{M}{2}$, etc...)

---

Well, while $(1)$ seems correct, I would vote for $(2)$, the argument would be that negative gravitational energy is compensating positive non-gravitational energy (mass energy)

Comment: To be clear, this isn't actually a question from a real educational quiz, is it? I think it's better not to present it as one unless it is actually from a quiz.

Comment: @DavidZ : The quiz presentation corresponds to my own interrogations.

Comment: #2 would violate conservation of mass-energy in the formation of a black hole by gravitational collapse. The mass-energy would start out being well approximated by Newtonian physics and would therefore be positive.

Comment: @BenCrowell : Yes, this is a very convincing argument in the case of the formation of a black hole by gravitational collapse. But something is boring me: if the negative gravitational energy increases, it must be compensated by a positive non-gravitational energy (to respect the conservation of the total energy), and I don't see exactly how.

Comment: @Trimok: Potential/Kientic energy distinctions will only lead you down a rabbit hole of confusion when doing general relativity.  It's much better to just find the total energy (when it exists), say it's conserved, and look at what consequences that has for motion.

Comment: @Trimok: In the nonrelativistic context, that positive energy would appear in forms like heat. In a black hole, that heat is part of the mass-energy that ends up in the singularity.

Answer (score 5):

The asymptotic flatness of black hole solutions enables one to define a surface at infinity that has time translation symmetry, and therefore, the evolution along here allows one to define a conjugate energy that represents the energy inside the surface at infinity.  This is known as the ADM energy.  If this is done, you will find that $E=M$